# How do you make a floated element fill the remaining horizontal space when it is between its fixed width siblings?

Tags: css, css-float

I am trying to create an accordion menu with multiple floated elements. I want all of the inactive menu items to collapse to a small fixed width (40px or so) and the active item to expand to the remaining width. I want the menu to be responsive/elastic, so only the inactive menu items will have fixed widths.

Below is an example of what I want my menu to look/function like (without using jQuery to set the widths)...

[Accordionza - CodeCanyon.com](http://codecanyon.net/item/accordionza-jquery-plugin/full_screen_preview/101685)

I was able to accomplish the desired effect when only two menu items are displayed by floating one of the elements and giving it a fixed width, while NOT floating the elastic item and giving it a width of 100%.

**Two Columns (Works)**

```
<style type="text/css">
    #one {
        float:left;
        width:40px;
    }
    #two {
        width:100%;
    }
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col" id="one">One</div>
    <div class="col elastic" id="two">Two</div>
</div>
```

**Four Columns - Elastic In Between (Does Not Work)**

```
<style type="text/css">
    #one, #three, #four {
        float:left;
        width:40px;
    }
    #two {
        width:100%;
    }
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col" id="one">One</div>
    <div class="col elastic" id="two">Two</div>
    <div class="col" id="three">Three</div>
    <div class="col" id="four">Four</div>
</div>
```

*Please note: applying `float:right;` to the elements to the right of the elastic item did not work either...*

The problem is that if the elastic element is NOT on the end of the row, then the menu items do not remain on a single row. Please examine the fiddle below to see what I mean...

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/derekfoulk/aQEt3/)

So how do I apply this desired elasticity to the elements that reside in between their siblings? I really really want to keep the markup as simple as possible. Thanks in advance!

**Update:** I am getting close to a solution, however there is a slight problem with every method I've attempted. I will break them down, along with the issues I'm running into with each one.

**METHOD 1: *display: table-cell;*** (Suggested by onetrickpony)

Seemed like the answer, however there will not always be contents (text or html) inside the slide elements, and elements formatted with the `display: table-cell;` property do not recognize applied widths unless there is content inside of them. So this only works if I have content inside the slide... (I could modify the markup of my slider, but I would like to keep it the way I have it).

**METHOD 2: *CSS calc()*** (Also suggested by onetrickpony)

Not supported by some of the browsers I would like it to be... [CaniIUse.com Browser Support Chart for calc()](http://caniuse.com/calc). Another excellent possibilty! One I did not know existed, and could be utilized if I made a fallback JS script for older browsers (want to avoid).

**METHOD 3: *Flexbox*** (Also suggested by onetrickpony)

Probably my favorite solution, but limited support is making me timid. Also could be used along with a fallback script. I learned about this a while back, and this is the future of CSS and layouts. Our salvation! Can't wait for full support...

**METHOD 4: *jQuery*** (Suggested by Tomasz Golinski)

What I was originally going to use, but decided I wanted to see if there was a CSS method that could be used instead. I have had some issues when using jQuery to set the width of elements. Mainly when the container is resized, and the script calculates the appropriate width while the container is resized.

So, the kind people who responded to my question have provided me with viable solutions to this issue. Any of the below is certainly an acceptable method to do what I am asking. I am simply seeking an answer that is more of a common CSS method. I am hoping that it is possible to accomplish this with some combination of styles I have not tried. I will admit I think Tomasz is correct- it cannot be done. I am leaving this question open just in case someone has a solution for me. Both Tomasz and onetrickpony have given me great answers. But I am still seeking a CSS-only solution that is widely supported by older browsers- and new, that I do not need to include a secondary script for, and that works without the need for characters inside the elements. Just want to see someone prove us wrong (that it is possible with good old fashioned CSS). If this magic answer does not come, I will be marking onetrickpony's answer as the best solution due to the fact it is CSS based, and he provided multiple solutions that are clean and simple. A combination of his flexbox CSS and Tomasz jQuery (as the secondary script) will most likely be what I use. Thanks!

Comment: well, one thing is for sure, if you set elastic to `width:100%`, it will take up the entire row, which is probably why the rest of the menu items jump a line...

Comment: basically because you make the item to be 100% width, the next items have no space to fit in the line so they appear under. If you have dynamic number of slides/items, you cannot do it with pure HTML and CSS. You need to use javascript to calculate 100% width - each closed slide = width of the open slide.

Comment: Well it should be possible lol... I've been reading into using `overflow:hidden;` on the elastic div or some combination of previously attempted configurations. I may have to fold and use jQuery. I just wanted to try everything possible (CSS) before using JS. I'm not sure if using some absolutely positioned children like many other accordion menus use is a better option. I just figured since I can achieved what I wanted to with two cols, it may be possible with multiple cols. Then use jQuery to transfer the "elastic" class when clicked. Thanks for your input Tomasz! I appreciate it!

Comment: @webeno - Definitely a possibility... But if not set to auto or 100%, then the desired stretch cannot be accomplished without setting fixed widths. I just remember some weird style combination of `position:absolute;` and `width:100%;` or something like that that makes an element stretch to width and height 100%. There might have been something with `overflow:hidden;` or something in there also. I don't know. I figured there may be something strange like this that would accomplish what I am trying to. About to set a bounty on this question lol. I refuse to accept it is not possible.

Comment: Hello, would you mind adding your solution as an actual _answer_ to the question? This helps our system curate it over time, and allows folks to vote on the answer. If not, we'll need to move it ourselves, which stinks, because it wouldn't be properly attributed to you.

Comment: Hi @TimPost - Are you asking me to post a solution? I don't believe that I ever successfully produced one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're set to use floats, calculate the width of your "elastic" column by subtracting the widths of other columns from 100%. Example:

```
<div class="row cols-4">
    <div class="col" id="one">One</div>
    <div class="col" id="two">Two</div>
    <div class="col elastic" id="three">Three</div>
    <div class="col" id="four">Four</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cols-4 .elastic{
   width: calc(100% - 45px * 3);
}

/* add more rules for other possible variations here */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QM4LZ/

---

But a cleaner and easier approach is to use [flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes). This is exactly what they were designed for.

```
.row{
    display: flex;
}

.col{
    flex: none;  /* <- don't flex */
    width: 45px;
}

.elastic{
    flex: auto; /* <- flex */
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F7sxU/

---

It's also possible to achieve this with tables ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Sfkq/)), but you'll most likely run into some limitations when adding the real content and you need more wrapper elements.

Comment: That is great advice. Unfortunately, flex isn't totally supported and my user base will be varied (browser wise), thus I need support for as many older browsers as possible. In the future, flex will definately be the go to method! Thank you for the response :)

Comment: It's supported by all browsers except IE 9 and lower. IE 10 implements an older draft of the specs, but it still works if you add the appropriate properties. If you have to support IE 9, you could always fall back to floats+calc(), and some javascript for IE 6-8

Comment: I just looked at the `display:table-cell;` solution in your last paragraph, and that may be my best option (if using floats is not viable). I do have to ask, what limitations are you referring to (when adding content)?

Comment: It depends on what content will the cells hold. Table elements don't support all the properties that the block-level elements do

Comment: I was going to leave the <div>'s empty, but the width(s) set in the CSS do not apply to the slides unless there is contents in the slides. (Remove the text "One", "Two", "Three", and "Four" from each element to see what I mean)... http://jsfiddle.net/derekfoulk/WhF2y/

Comment: I guess you`ll have to add some dummy content in them, like a space (`&nbsp;`)

Answer (score 1):

the previous answer does resolve the issue however there are some problems with @onetrickpony's solution

example #1 will not work properly with dynamic number of items.

example #2 in most browsers it will work but not all browsers do support flexible boxes.

here is simple javascript code

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aQEt3/5/

```
var count = $('.row').children().length; // counts how many items are in the entire row
var totWidth = $('.row').width(); // checks total width of the row
var elWidth = totWidth - ((count - 1) * 45); // counts how wide should be the elastic it

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.elastic').css('width', elWidth); // when document is ready, apply the new width to the elastic
});
```

beware, this is very simple code and there will be some issues if:

*there are 2 or more `.row` items

*you have more than one elastic class

Comment: This is excellent as well, I would really like to do this width without the jQuery though. The container (wrapper) is a fluid width container, and I don't want the browser/script to set the width constantly (when resizing the window). I used jQuery to adjust widths based on the width of another element before, and it really degraded the animation of resizing the window. How many people are going to be playing with their windows like that? Not too many I'm sure, but I really want to stick with good 'ole CSS if at all possible. And I would like to be able to utilize multiple rows...

Comment: it will work as well with any width, even if you put width in percentage. as it takes the width of the wrapper at the time the website it's ready. It's easy fix to make it work on window resize (so it will adjust the width on every window size change). you just have to run same thing inside `$(window).resize(function(){...});` (or javascript: `window.onresize = function() {...}`).. if you want pure javascript then it will get a bit more complicated.. If you stick with CSS then you will have issues with compatibility and dynamic item number (as I stated above).